# Labeling Poles in Sequential Order on Data Driven Pages Along Curvy Route?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, data-driven-pages

Is there a way to automate the process of labeling poles #'s on data driven pages along a curvy route in sequential order?

The many bends and turns of the route is throwing off the ordering. the snippet is a visual representation of our problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [python script](http://codepad.org/PnkZoefh) that does this for water meter routing. Just draw a line from the start to end of your points, set up your labeling and push go.

If I remember correctly, the guts of it basically grabs one point at a time, gets the geometry and snaps it to the line. Then it finds the % along the line that that point is and adds it to a long list. After its gone through all the points, it sorts the points in the list based on the % from smallest to largest. After sorting it numbers the points in order of the sort.

You might have to adapt my code to your means but it should do your trick.

[I wrote it up on linked in](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/arcmap-add-points-line-along-route-barrett-burnworth?trk=mp-author-card) if you want to read my full description.

I think the code is dependent upon a function introduced in arcmap 10.2.1 :  line.measureOnLine()

Answer (score 1):

I see this as a classic linear referencing problem.

1. [Create routes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/create-routes.htm) from your line feature class
2. [Locate features along routes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/locate-features-along-routes.htm) (features = light poles)
3. [Sort](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm) by measure
4. Label

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be to sort the point features spatially. Using the Sort function in your script, you can choose from which corner you want to start labeling (the 4 or 8 cardinal directions are supported). Make sure you select spatial rather than one of the fields in your attribute (I think you just need to specify the shape field)